# Target Audience Not Working - Navigation Link

Tags: navigation, audience-targeting

I'm setting a target audience for my SharePoint subsite navigation link. However, I've been testing with people (not in Target Audience) and they are still able to view/access the link on the site.

Why isn't the target audience working?